enumerating contiguous ones in kdb+
Given a list of 0s and 1s, say l: 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 I would like to get a sequence beginning with 1 for each contiguous set of 1s. Thus the required output should be l: 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2. How can I achieve this in kdb+?

You can use scan:
q){y*x+y}scan 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2


appreciate the help once again.

Quite an interesting solution!

There is a built-in shortcut for this sort of task (though only works for floats)
q)l:0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1f
q)0 l\l
0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2f

see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#alternative-syntax
It was designed mainly for exponential moving average calculations

could you explain what's happening here?

Sorry yes, forgot to add link to docs. See link above
